# SQL Server - Query with Join and mutiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to query four table as below:

**Table1**: Users

```
User  | Name
-------------
01    | Phil
-------------
02    | John
-------------
03    | Marc
-------------
04    | Rob
```

Order: Integer and Incremental / Name: varchar

**Table2**: Status

```
Status | Description
--------------------
   01  | Canceled
--------------------
   02  | Confirmed
--------------------
   03  | Bulding
--------------------
   ..  | .....
--------------------
   15  | Finished
```

Status: Integer and Incremental / Description: varchar

**Table3**: Build

```
 Order |    Date    | Place
----------------------------
   01  | 01/01/2014 |  MG
----------------------------
   02  | 02/02/2014 |  SP
----------------------------
   05  | 03/03/2014 |  BA
```

Order: Integer / Date: Date / Place: Varchar

**Table4**: Orders

```
Order | User | Status
-----------------------
01    |  02  |   01
-----------------------
02    |  01  |   11
-----------------------
03    |  03  |   15
-----------------------
04    |  01  |   03
-----------------------
05    |  04  |   02
```

Order: Integer and Incremental / User: Integer / Status: Integer

I have to query Table 4 to show all orders (except status 1,15) join with table 01, table 02 and table 03 ordering by date at table 03. The problem is table 03 not always have a row with the order number and the this order doesn't show at query.

I need a result like this:

**Query Result**:

```
Order | User | Name | Status | Description |   Date     | Place
----------------------------------------------------------------
02    |  01  | Phil |   11   |  Painting   | 02/02/2014 |  SP
----------------------------------------------------------------
05    |  04  | Rob  |   02   |  Confirmed  | 03/03/2014 |  BA
----------------------------------------------------------------
04    |  01  | Phil |   03   |  Bulding    |            |
```

Thanks for the help !!!

Comment: This looks like a school assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "LEFT OUTER JOIN" for table 3.  That will return all the records in the other tables, the matches in table 3, and if table 3 doesn't match, it will show up blank.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN Build ON Order.Order = Build.Order
```

This will return all of the results for Orders and the matches from Build.  Note, the table you want to keep all the records from must go on the LEFT side of the ON statement (ON Order.Order = Build.Order).

More info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the anwser, this solve my problem to join empty rows, but and the rest like, condition NOT Status 01 or 15, join with others tables and order the result by Build.Date...

Comment: I tried with more codes and reach at result with this query:  SELECT Order.Order, Order.User, User.Name, Order.Status, Status.Description, Build.Date, Build.Place
FROM User, Status, Order
LEFT OUTER JOIN Build ON Order.Order = Build.Order
WHERE Order.Status <> 01
AND Order.Status <> 15
AND Order.Client = User.User
AND Order.Status = Status.Status
Order By Build.Order Desc